# Deleting a record using id in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to delete record using the get id method. I embeded html within php in the echo part.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select)) {
    echo("<tr>
            <td>". $row[games_name] ."</td>
            <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
            <td> <a href='delete.php?id={$row['games_id']}'>delete</a></td>
          </tr>");
}
```

In my delete.php I entered the following:

```
incude("includes/connection.php");
$id = $_GET["id"];

$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_games WHERE games_id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con).mysql_error();
if(!result){ echo "Error";}else{echo "Success";}
```

but it doesnt seem to work. Any help please!!

Comment: Any output error to share with us? is it id, or games_id in your WHERE condition?

Comment: it must be `WHERE id=$id`. And do not use deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statement

Comment: No, it directs to the other page. But when i check the record is not deleted. Im deleting it using the games_id

Comment: I cant see the use of `games_id` anywhere in your code

Comment: sql injections ahead...

Comment: its there in  <a href='delete.php?id={$row['games_id']}'>

Comment: In your table tbl_games what is the id? id or games_id?

Comment: in tbl_games it is games_id

Comment: then you should change the query with: DELETE FROM tbl_games WHERE games_id=$id

Comment: i tried still it doesnt delete

Comment: Does your MySQL user have permission to `DELETE`? What does `mysql_error()` say?

Comment: Remove the redirection after the execution of the delete and find out if there is an error output. You need to debug, otherwise hardly somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: well, there are no errors it only echos my  echo "deleted"; But does not effect to my database

Comment: @Andrew make your code become `mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());` then tell us the results. Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123018/deleting-a-record-using-id-in-php#comment46472996_29123018

Comment: As @Masiorama specified can you provide us with any outputed errors.
Use var_dump to confirm values of your variables and also check your logs. Its hard to debug with the minimal info you provided.

Comment: Enable error output, print out your `$sql` and see if the query itself works in phpMyAdmin (or CLI or something else). "Stupid" question: you are connected to a MySQLserver, right? (`$con`)

Comment: yes, my $sql deosnt work. when i check in phpMyAdmin the records are not deleted

Comment: once i click my delete link i get into my delete.php and this url is found on the address bar http://localhost/sports/delete.php?id=

Comment: so it seems `?id=` is blank

Comment: this code is now in my delete php incude("includes/connection.php");

$id = $_GET["id"];

$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_games WHERE games_id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con).mysql_error();
if(!result){
 echo "Error";
}else{
 echo "Success";
}

Comment: `incude` should be `include`.

Comment: Thanks but still it deosnt show any effect on my database

Answer (score 1):

There are several typos/errors in your code. If you want, change your while loop to:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select)) {
  echo sprintf("
    <tr>
      <td>%s</td>
      <td>%s</td>
      <td><a href=\"delete.php?id=%d\">delete</a></td>
    </tr>", $row["games_name"], $row["date"], $row["games_id"]);
}
```

(The added `sprintf()` makes the html more readable I think.)

You were missing quotes in `$row[games_name]` so I changed that.

For your `delete.php`:

```
incude("includes/connection.php");
$id = isset($_GET["id"]) ? (int)$_GET["id"] : null ;
if ( !isset($id) ) {
  die("Error: id not set");
}
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_games WHERE games_id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());
if (!$result) {
  echo "Error";
} else {
  echo "Success";
}
```

Make sure this only gets executed when `?id` is set.

Changed your `incude` to `include`, `!result` to `!$result`.

(Untested code)

Comment: the id url showed a value yet didnt effect the database. can you please tell me what do you mean by id=%d

Comment: `%d` is a format parameter for `sprintf()`: "_the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as a (signed) decimal number._" http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Since it didn't affect your database and your query also didn't work in phpMyAdmin: make sure your database user has the proper rights to delete from `tbl_games`.

Comment: nice... There must me some problem in my code that deosnt work

Comment: There sure must be ;) If you redo your code, do as @Jens suggested and switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the Curly braces **{}** from PHP file URL `{$row['games_id']}` and remove the braces in delete query too.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_games WHERE id=$id"
```

Comment: no, `"{$var}"` variables wrapped inside curly braces inside double quoted strings will work. but of course prone to SQL injection in the OP's case

Comment: When i remove the braces in  '{$row['games_id']}' i get a blank page